# How to call numberOfRowsInSection and cellForRowAtIndexPath alternatively

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios4, tableview

I am working on an application in which data is displaying from back end to tableview.
The problem is, when table is loading, it gets all the data but displays only the last entry of database in each row. suppose last section has 3 rows then it displays only3 that 3 row data in each section.Even if in some section rows are 9 then the rest of rows are displaying blank.

I found it through break points that table first takes all the data from database and then read cellForRowAtIndexPath, As in my database last table has 3 rows, it displays the data of 3 rows only by keeping  rest of rows blank.

Here is the coe of my  numberOfRowsInSection and cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.

    if(requestType == 2) 
    {       
        if (self.uniqueCityCount > 0) 
        {
            NSString *strCity = [self.arrayCityNames objectAtIndex:section];            //@"EventData" :@"EventCity"
            NSPredicate *predicateSettings =  [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(EventCity = %@ )",strCity]; 
            if ([self.arrayEventDescription count]>0)
            {
                [self.arrayEventDescription removeAllObjects];
            }
            self.arrayEventDescription = [CoreDataAPIMethods searchObjectsInContext:@"EventData" :predicateSettings :@"EventCity" :YES :self.managedObjectContext];
            return [self.arrayEventDescription count];  
        }
        /*
         if (section == 0)
         {
         NSString *strCity = [self.arrayCityNames objectAtIndex:section];           //@"EventData" :@"EventCity"
         NSPredicate *predicateSettings =  [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(EventCity = %@ )",strCity]; 
         self.arrayEventDescription = [CoreDataAPIMethods searchObjectsInContext:@"EventData" :predicateSettings :@"EventCity" :YES :self.managedObjectContext];
         return [self.arrayEventDescription count]; 
         }
         else if (section == 1)
         {

         }*/
    }       
return 0;
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{    
NSString *CellIdentifier = [@"" stringByAppendingFormat:@"Cell%d",indexPath.row];      
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

if(requestType == 2)
{   
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

        //  for (int j = 0 ; j < [self.arrayEventDescription count]; j++)

        //  for(int j=0; j<[tableView numberOfSections]; j++)

        //{

        NSLog(@"at section %d",indexPath.section);
        NSLog(@"at row %d",indexPath.row);
        NSLog(@"array count %d",[self.arrayEventDescription count]);

        if (indexPath.row < [self.arrayEventDescription count]) 
        {


            EventData *data = [self.arrayEventDescription objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            //EventData *data = [self.arrayEventDescription objectAtIndex:j];

            cell.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
            cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];      


            //  UIView *viewDescription = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(00, 00, 480, 35)];

            //////////////////////    Labels for description of city events from database  ////////////////////////////             

            UILabel *lblEvent = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 00, 150, 30)];
            lblEvent.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
            lblEvent.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

            UILabel *lblEventAtDate = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200, 00, 150, 30)];
            lblEventAtDate.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
            lblEventAtDate.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

            UILabel *lblEventAtSchool = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(350, 15, 150, 30)];
            lblEventAtSchool.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
            lblEventAtSchool.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

            [cell.contentView addSubview:lblEvent];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:lblEventAtDate];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:lblEventAtSchool];


            lblEvent.text = data.EventName;
            //  lblEventAtDate.text = data.EventDate;
            lblEventAtSchool.text = data.EventPlace;
        }



        //} 
    }
}


// Configure the cell...

return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a first thing, I moved everything out of cell == nil block, as reuse may not happen. See if this solves your problem.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{    

NSString *CellIdentifier = [@"" stringByAppendingFormat:@"Cell%d",indexPath.row];      
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

if(requestType == 2)
{   
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

        //  for (int j = 0 ; j < [self.arrayEventDescription count]; j++)

        //  for(int j=0; j<[tableView numberOfSections]; j++)

        //{

        NSLog(@"at section %d",indexPath.section);
        NSLog(@"at row %d",indexPath.row);
        NSLog(@"array count %d",[self.arrayEventDescription count]);





        //} 
    }

    if (indexPath.row < [self.arrayEventDescription count]) 
    {


        EventData *data = [self.arrayEventDescription objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        //EventData *data = [self.arrayEventDescription objectAtIndex:j];

        cell.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];      


        //  UIView *viewDescription = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(00, 00, 480, 35)];

        //////////////////////    Labels for description of city events from database  ////////////////////////////             

        UILabel *lblEvent = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 00, 150, 30)];
        lblEvent.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
        lblEvent.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

        UILabel *lblEventAtDate = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200, 00, 150, 30)];
        lblEventAtDate.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
        lblEventAtDate.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

        UILabel *lblEventAtSchool = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(350, 15, 150, 30)];
        lblEventAtSchool.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
        lblEventAtSchool.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

        [cell.contentView addSubview:lblEvent];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:lblEventAtDate];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:lblEventAtSchool];


        lblEvent.text = data.EventName;
        //  lblEventAtDate.text = data.EventDate;
        lblEventAtSchool.text = data.EventPlace;
    }
}


// Configure the cell...

return cell;
```

}

Comment: data is displaying in the same previous way but this time, the same data overlapping againg ad again thus letters are seen in bold due to overlapping.

Comment: I can see your CGRectMake creating controls repeatedly at the same screen coordinates. Can you consider using custom table cell for this. Please refer: http://www.e-string.com/content/custom-uitableviewcells-interface-builder

Answer (score 0):

Can you tell me what is the request type and when it will be called(a set of possible values).

Quick Solution: You are checking the condition of request type first `if(requestType == 2) {`  and then you are loading the cell. This delegate method will be called on loading the tableview, but requesttype is 2. So for indexpath.row=0 & 1, it wont go inside to load the cell and it loads only for requesttype=2. So it is loading third row.

Comment: RequestType is an integer.Actually I have 4 subViews Attaching to the xib View. This is the second view of mine n thus Request type 2 will be called on displaying the 2nd view in which i have the table view as discussed above.

Comment: RequestType is just an integer and i have already define in number of sections that if RequestType is 2 then the number of section are of array count. so i dont think that RequestType can create any problem. I am using ReuestType for distinguishing the Four Views As each View containing a table.